# Which Velocity is used to measure Dynamic Pressure?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

Suppose an airplane is flying in windy conditions. Now, for the calculation of the dynamic pressure should I use the relative velocity or the absolute velocity as the free stream airspeed?

Comment: A wing only cares about he airmass it is moving in. Thus you must take speed of the wing/the aircraft relative to the airmass you are flying in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the speed of the air relative to the object.

Take the extreme example of a stationary wind turbine. It obviously experiences aerodynamic forces and dynamic pressure, yet always has an absolute speed of zero.